# join() method doesn't waits for thread to end

Tags: android, multithreading

I have an AsyncTask, and in its doInBackground method I call a method in another class:

```
@Override
protected ArrayList<CustomClass> doInBackground(ArrayList<CustomClass>...  array) {
    ArrayList<CustomClass> retorno= DataNetwork.GetCustomClassArrayList(array[0],(...more parameters...));
    return retorno;
}
```

In DataNetwork I have that method, which does a REST call, and returns a result. I am forced to use a library that makes the REST call (I think it uses Volley, but I am not sure. To call this library, I have to make an Intent, which is passed to the method makeRESTCall):

```
public static ArrayList<CustomClass> GetCustomClassArrayList(various params goes here){
ArrayList<CustomClass> toReturn;
    //some parameters processing
    library.makeRESTCall(Intent intent){
        //processing the answer
        toReturn=processAnswerJSONResponse();
    }
return toReturn;
}
```

This way, I get to the return toReturn line, before answer from REST is processed. So, I tried to make a Thread, and use the join statement. The GetCustomClassArrayList method (well, most of it, until the t.start()) is now inside a Thread. The end of the method is now:

```
(...)
 t.start();
    try {
        t.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return toReturn;
```

The execution calls t.join() immediately after t.start(); and toReturn is null.

Maybe is a noob question, but using the method join() always worked for me, and waited for the thread to finish before entering the return statement. No exception, no error. It just doesn't wait for the thread to finish.

Why is not working now? What can I do to wait for the toReturn variable to be fulfilled before entering the return statement?

Thank you.

Comment: Re, "The execution calls `t.join()` immediately after `t.start()`." That almost never makes sense. Why start a new thread if the already-existing thread has no work to do until after the new thread finishes? You might just as well call `t.run()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem likely stems from using a library which is already returning the response asynchronously, so your `AsyncTask` is not blocking. Check the library documentation.

`AsyncTask` is not like a normal thread. It is specialized to execute one time, blocking if necessary in the `doInBackground` method, then returning results to be handled in the main thread. If your 3rd party REST library has a synchronous version of it's calls, you could use that in your `AsyncTask`, but it will likely be less efficient than the library's built in functionality.

Comment: "Check the library documentation"... that made me laugh. Its an internal library, and there is no documentation...Thanks for your response anyway.

Comment: If it's an internal library, I'd recommend looking further into its code to see what it is doing with the callback/closure you are providing.  If it is saving it off then later posting it to a `Handler` or using some other mechanism to call it back on a specific thread (such as using RxJava/RxAndroid schedulers) then you can most likely get rid of the `AsyncTask` usage completely.  Just be sure your code is setup to handle things asynchronously.